# how to get current zoom level from scene window

Tags: unity, editors

I want to show some label on some rect transforms using `Handles.Label()`. it shows the text with a default font size regardless of the zoom level in the scene window.

```
public class NodeWrapper : MonoBehaviour {

    public Node node;

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Handles.Label(transform.position + new Vector3(-.9f, .5f), node.Name);
        Handles.Label(transform.position + new Vector3(-.9f, .4f), node.Info);
        ...
    }
}
```

So when I zoom out in the scene window, the labels get closer and at some point they become unreadable. I want to show/hide some lines when zoom level changes. How can I achieve that? Is it possible to get the current zoom level of the scene?

### edit

PS. I'm developing a node editor for another game, I use scene window to create and serialize some objects. My target is only **Scene window** which uses **2D** config.

[image]

Comment: how are you handling zoom? perspective or orthographic camera?

Comment: I forgot to mention it's a 2D scene so it's orthographic.

Comment: what kind of objects are the ones that hold the text?

Comment: if you mean the rectangles they are UI.Image. but the text is being drawn using Handles.Label()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the `Handles.Label` function to work in different zoom levels you need to change two things:

1. Use the function signature that accepts `GUIStyle`
2. Calculate the `fontSize` while considering the `orthographicSize` of the scene camera.

For example:

```
// this is the internal camera rendering the scene view, not the main camera!
float zoom = SceneView.currentDrawingSceneView.camera.orthographicSize;

// the style object allows you to control font size, among many other settings
var style = new GUIStyle();

// this value depends on your scene, tweak it to match the other objects
int fontSize = 70; 

// as you zoom out, the ortho size actually increases, 
// so dividing by it makes the font smaller which is exactly what we need
style.fontSize = Mathf.FloorToInt(fontSize / zoom);

Handles.Label(transform.position + new Vector3(-.9f, .5f), node.Name, style);
```

Answer (score 1):

docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-orthographicSize.html , orthographicSize value is your zoom, make a script to get that value from the main.camera and manipulate the labels according to that value.

small example,

```
public Camera cam;
private float orthoZoom;

void Update() {
  orthoZoom = cam.orthographicSize;
}
```

Comment: thank you but my scene doesn't require a camera. I don't run my project I just use the scene window to create and serialize some gameobjects.

Comment: yea I understood that, but by default every scene that will use your editor script will have a Camera set on ortographic otherwise the scene wont be visible. so you just have to check if there is a camera and if its true then your editor can work.

Comment: as I said there is no camera in the scene. I added a picture to demonstrate my goal.

Comment: There's no camera in the scene, but there *is* a hidden camera rendering the editor's scene view. You can get a reference to it in `OnDrawGizmos` (and maybe other methods) using `UnityEditor.SceneView.currentDrawingSceneView.camera`

Answer (score 0):

I tested, and it worked!

```
float zoom = SceneView.currentDrawingSceneView.size;
float fontSize = 300f; 
var style = new GUIStyle();
style.fontSize = Mathf.FloorToInt(fontSize / zoom);
```